How do I filter what images I receive from a Ticketmaster API?
I have "Widget" in my app that im using as a button for a Featured scrollView. The problem im having is that when I call the images from the api it displays them how I want but it repeats the same image several time before showing a new image. Im wanting a different image for each widget.
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct HomeViewWidget: View {
    var event: Event 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let imageUrl = event.images?.first?.url {
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: imageUrl))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(10)


That is my Actual widget.
this is my view im calling my widget onto.
import SwiftUI

struct HomePageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBarView().padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Featured")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .padding() 
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(events, id: \.id) { event in
                            HomeViewWidget(event: event)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Explore Events", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Welcome \(userSettings.profile.name)")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text("Explore events")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .onAppear {
                loadEvents()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func loadEvents() {
        Task {
            do {
                let loadedEvents = try await fetchTMEvents() ?? []  // Fetch events
                let uniqueEvents = Array(Set(loadedEvents)).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }  // Remove duplicates and sort
                let limitedEvents = Array(uniqueEvents.prefix(3))  // Limit to 5 events for display

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.events = limitedEvents  // Update UI with limited number of events
                    limitedEvents.forEach { event in
                        print("Unique Event Displayed: \(event.name), ID: \(event.id)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Failed to load events: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomePageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomePageView().environmentObject(UserSettings())
    }
}

private func uniqueEvents(from events: [Event]) -> [Event] {
    var uniqueIds = Set<String>()
    return events.filter { uniqueIds.insert($0.id).inserted }
}

And here is my data that ive been trying to use to filter the images:
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let name, type, id, url, locale: String
    let images: [EventImage]?
}

extension Event: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}


Don't combine modern async/await tasks with dispatch queues. Use a .task rather than a .onAppear.

You can also use SwiftUI's inbuilt AsyncImage

In SwiftUI it's .task for the correct async lifetime not Task

Also == needs to compare everything not just the id.

In SwiftUI you must use .task and not Task so you get the correct lifetime, e.g. it is cancelled on disappear. You also shouldn't use DispatchQueue from a View struct but you can safely update state from .task.
      .task {
            await loadEvents()
       }
    }
    
    
    private func loadEvents() async {
            do {
                let loadedEvents = try await fetchTMEvents() ?? []  // Fetch events
                let uniqueEvents = Array(Set(loadedEvents)).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }  // Remove duplicates and sort
                let limitedEvents = Array(uniqueEvents.prefix(3))  // Limit to 5 events for display

                    self.events = limitedEvents  // Update UI with limited number of events
                    limitedEvents.forEach { event in
                        print("Unique Event Displayed: \(event.name), ID: \(event.id)")
                    }
                
            } catch {
                    print("Failed to load events: \(error)")
                
            }
        }
    }

extension Event: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.url == rhs.url && lhs.name == rhs.name && everything else...
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(url)
        hasher.combine(name)
        and everything else...
    }

Note you can get automatic Hashable conformance to save you some code if you follow this: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-get-equatable-and-hashable-for-free/
